# SharePoint 2019 removes hash (#), anchor links from address - changes to question mark (?)

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint 2019

Three is a library with many documents. I'd like to use anchor links for automatic scrolling to a concrete document, for ex.:

https://sp-host/my-lib/Forms/AllItems.aspx#my-doc

I created these anchor links with the help of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting. In library in document list I can see anchor links for each document in the corresponding field.

But the matter of fact is that SharePoint 2019 removes hash (#), anchor links from address and changes it to question mark (?) during my try to use an anchor link in browser address filed, for ex.:

https://sp-host/my-lib/Forms/AllItems.aspx?my-doc

After that automatic scrolling to a concrete document doesn't occur.

Please advise me how I can fix that? Why does SharePoint 2019 remove hash (#), anchor links from address and change it to question mark (?)? How can I adjust, setup SharePoint 2019?

I searched possible fixes in Internet but failed. I found that there exists a well-known corresponding issue for Angular with workaround as path handling should be changed - don't use hash (#) in paths. I also played with MDS feature (https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/02/disable-minimal-download-strategy-mds-in-sharepoint-2013.html) — but also failed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at the following link for the answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299976/sharepoint-2019-removes-hash-anchor-links-from-address-changes-to-questio/299995#299995